# Shared Libraries linking against static libraries with common interface but different implementations

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, ld

NB: *Bear with me as this is convoluted. It is also legacy software designed for windows that I am attempting to port to be compatible with C++ standards / Linux. I am only going to give some high level examples that I have been able to reproduce the problem with as I won't be able to give examples of our production code. Please don't ask why we do this, just know that we do and I have to deal with it.*

We have a number of static libraries that are used by shared libraries. eg FirstSharedLib.so and SecondSharedLib.so both depend on CommonStaticLibrary.lib.

Now, CommonStaticLibrary.lib declares methods that are intended to be implemented by the Shared libraries. Example, GetSharedLibraryName();

So the FirstSharedLib project implements GetSharedLibraryName for CommonStaticLibrary by returning "FirstSharedLib", likewise SecondSharedLib implements it by returning "SecondSharedLib".

This works as intended in windows, eg, when FirstSharedLib calls GetSharedLibraryName(); it receives the "FirstSharedLib" string and then likewise when SecondSharedLib calls GetSharedLibraryName(); it receives the "SecondSharedLib" string.

However when compiling and running In Linux (gcc/ld), The dynamic linker loads the first shared library, sees the implementation of  CommonStaticLibrary::GetSharedLibraryName() and then uses that for every other sharedlibrary that calls GetSharedLibraryName(), regardless of actual implementation.

So in this case if FirstSharedLib is loaded first, when it calls GetSharedLibraryName(); it receives the "FirstSharedLib" string but when SecondSharedLib is loaded it will also receive "FirstSharedLib".

Alternatively, if SecondSharedLib is loaded first, all calls to GetSharedLibraryName() return "SecondSharedLib".

Is there a linker option to prelink the shared impementations of the static libraries so that when SecondSharedLib calls GetSharedLibraryName() it always invokes the implementation created by that project?

Note that I can see pointers to the unique implementations in memory when we load the shared libraries, its just that the runtime will always invoke the first loaded instantiation whenever any other library calls it.

We are using CMake as our build system, but that shouldn't be too relevant other than the fact I will use CMake commands to pass linker and/or compiler flags.

I have tried using -fPIC to compile the shared libraries as well as setting the visiblity of the common library methods to hidden in an attempt to limit its access, but neither options have worked. We have also tried to modify some of the signatures of the Common library methods but we are limited in the amount we can change this.

Comment: If you want the APIs in CommonStaticLibrary to be internal to each shared library, have a look at the GCC wiki on [visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).  One big difference between the default Windows and Linux build systems is that on Linux, everything is exported by default, so the symbols conflict between each library.

Comment: @TavianBarnes, thanks, we did try that. I used the Cmake CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET set to "hidden" as well as explicitly adding "-fvisibility=hidden" to the compiler flags. neither had a noticible effect.

Answer (score 1):

In our method where we were loading the dynamic libraries, we were passing the RTLD_GLOBAL which apparently was overriding our hidden attributes passed in when compiling.

We removed the RTLD_GLOBAL flag (replaced it with RTLD_LOCAL 0x0) and now the libraries keep the static library methods local to the instigating shared library. We were also able to remove the flags to set the attributes to hidden.

old code:

```
int flag = RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL;
void* library = dlopen( libraryName, flag );
```

new code:

```
int flag = RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL;
void* library = dlopen( libraryName, flag );
```